# Google Form Submission Values are Undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to capture some values from a form submission in a function and do some processing. So far, I'm having trouble just capturing values.

I have a very simple form set up with one field. I have the following code to pull the values and put them onto the Log.

```js
function myFunction(e) {

  var val1 = e.values;

  Logger.log(val1);

}
```

I have set up the appropriate triggers such that the script runs whenever I submit a form, however, I always end up logging undefined.

[14-10-27 21:58:16:451 EDT] undefined

I've done this before, so I'm wondering if I'm missing a step or if something is wrong with my setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the function:

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
```

Comment: The actual name of the function is not important... this is an installable trigger, you can choose any name you want.